# How to cast varchar on update?

Tags: sql, firebird

When I update t1 then `"VALUE"` field should increment
but this field is set to `VARCHAR` and I would cast it to `INTEGER`:

```
UPDATE t1 SET "VALUE"="VALUE"+1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT "VALUE" FROM t1 WHERE CAST(t1."VALUE" as INTEGER) = t2."VALUE");
```

Comment: Where is `t2` coming from?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it looks he is coming from some pseudo-SQL engine, like MySQL3 maybe, and what he actually needs is `MERGE` command. Just guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to cast `"VALUE"` to an integer to be able to increment it, so:

```
UPDATE t1 SET "VALUE" = CAST("VALUE" as INTEGER) + 1
```

Firebird will automatically convert the `INTEGER` back to a `VARCHAR` on assignment.

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=8397710961e993c0debb749a17d899b7).

That said, the proper way to handle this is to change you schema and use an `INTEGER` type for this column.

Answer (score 1):

You already types `WHERE CAST(t1."VALUE" as INTEGER)` - that is excatly what you have to do.

```
UPDATE t1 SET VALUE = CAST(CAST(VALUE as INTEGER) + 1 AS VarChar(10))
```

Like Mark said above.

---

What bugs me there is your `WHERE` clause.

`WHERE NOT EXISTS` may be very slow on interbase/firebird on data volumes above trivial. Back in 1990-s in Interbase 5.6 days i used such a consturct to calculalte MLM tree bottom-to-top. I see it advantageous because no unknown-depth recursion would be involved, and because if the tree gets split and would not be all accessible from one single root - for bototm-up ascend it makes no problem.

Turned out, is took about 2 hours for mere 60000 rows. Bosses, used to calc for weeks by pencil and paper, saw no troubles. But i knew something is very bad (it was - ignoring indices and using nested natural scans, O(n^2) scaling).

Think twice about using `WHERE NOT EXIST`, on some schemas and datas it would be okay or even best approach, on others can quickly escalate to practically unusable program. DailyWTF regularly writes about programs which worked perfectly on small datasets during development, but stopped to work few months after deployed to production. Granted, my first SQL program was exactly one of that kind...

---

Additionally, your query seems broken absolutely. What is `t2.VALUE` ? when you use equality expression you have to give a singleton, scalar value. But t2.Value is just a column, it can have zero rows or thousand rows.

This `WHERE` clause seems just broken, i believe you made it up and never actually run on the server. What was your real query? Right now your query looks like

```
 IF there is somewhere a row in T1, where value is same as (T2-VALUE constant???)
   THEN do nothing
   ELSE update every row in T1 by incrementing VALUE column
```

or was your intention different?

```
 IF there are any rows in T1 and T2 with the same value in their VALUE columns
   THEN do nothing
   ELSE update every row in T1 by incrementing VALUE column
```

In both cases, this is a one-time check, that has to be done once before UPDATE sequence, and instead you make it run again and again and again over ever T1 row. It is exactly a recipe to make non-scaling application.

Move expensive to calculate invariants out of the loop.

---

As a generic advice, to avoid multiple `WHERE NOT EXISTS` you have at least two generic enough tools.

1. Use Inversion of control. Make a PSQL block (a **stored procedure** or an anonymous `EXECUTE BLOCK`) with `for select ... do ...` loop.

Make usual `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` check, as the `WHERE NOT EXIST` ssubstitution.
Inside the loop only call UPDATE on those rows that have to be updated.

2. Use `MERGE` command, instead fo PSQL loops.

---

But most probably, your query has almost nothing with your real task at hands. So we can suggest nothing reasonable too.

Comment: Arioch 'The, a query that allows increasing by 1 all the values of the t1."VALUE" field of the table t1, if such values does not exist in t2."VALUE" of the t2 table.

Comment: @slaine then LEFT JOIN and MERGE are your friends. And, you query did not do what you say, as it shifted no correlation from current T1 row into WHERE clause. But trust me, almost always it would be bad idea to scan all T2 table for every T1 row again and again anyway